# Why is #each traverse order reversed when inside a component?

Tags: ember.js

[See the jsbin example here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qecipawesi/2/)

Here is my code:

```js
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];
  }
});

App.DerpMenuComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    items: null,
    createSteps: function() {
        this.set('items', Ember.ArrayProxy.create({content: []}));
    }.on('init'),
    register: function(item) {
        this.get('items').addObject(item);
    }
});

App.DerpMenuItemComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    title: null,
    register: function() {
        this.get('parentView').register(this);
    }.on('didInsertElement')
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://builds.handlebarsjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.8.0/ember.js"></script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>

    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
    {{#derp-menu}}
      {{#each item in model}}
        {{#derp-menu-item title=item}}
          <div style="background: #CCC; color: #00F; margin: 10px; padding: 5px">{{item}}</div>
        {{/derp-menu-item}}
      {{/each}}
    {{/derp-menu}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/derp-menu">
    <ul>
      {{#each item in items}}
        <li>{{item.title}}</li>
      {{/each}}
      {{yield}}
  </ul>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/derp-menu-item">
    {{yield}}
</script>
```

I can see, that the `derp-menu-elements` register in reverse order, when adding them into the template dinamically, using the `#each` helper. Can anyone please explain why that is the case? If I manually type out the `derp-menu-item`s inside the `derp-menu` component - everything is displayed correctly, I'm guessing that's because Handlebars somehow act differently in that scenario. Can anyone provide insights into what's happening in both of these cases?

Comment: Please add your code inside your question. Just linking to a jsbin or jsfiddle will probably get your question closed. See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'm sorry, will always embed my code from now on. Thank you for editing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `didInsertElement` event always fire from the last/lowest level and then moves up the tree. This is so that when `didInsertElement` is fired on a parent element you can be sure that all the children are already inserted in the dom.

In your case you are registering with the parent `.on('didInsertElement')` you are ending up with the elements getting added to the array in the reverse order.

If you changed your code to be based on `.on('init')` (like below) then they would get be in the same order.

```
App.DerpMenuItemComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    title: null,
    register: function() {
        this.get('parentView').register(this);
    }.on('init')
});
```

You can see a working example here: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/hirolu/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: But if I manually type out the elements (as seen here: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nitulirepa/2/) the order is preserved. Handlebars somehow preserves the order in this case?